# Version of Taylor expansion that gives $f(b)-f(a)$ precisely in terms of first and second derivative

Tags: calculus, reference-request, taylor-expansion

I'd like a result that says if $f\in C^2$ and $a<b$, then for some $c\in[a,b]$,

$$f(b)-f(a)=f'(a)(b-a)+\frac{1}{2}f''(c)(b-a)^2.$$

I would also greatly appreciate a book recommendation on basic results for Taylor series.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is just called Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder.

Comment: @Ian Perfect, thanks a bunch